# How to mock a redux-form field?

Tags: reactjs, sinon, redux-form

I am trying to mock a redux-form field in a unit test so that when onChange gets fired in my code the value gets updated. My field looks something like this:

```
myField: {
  value: false,
  onChange: () => {},
}
```

I have passed an empty function to onChange here as a placeholder for the purposes of asking this question but I know that I need to write some logic to update the value... I am not sure where to begin with that though.

In the component that I am unit testing the onChange gets called like so:

```
this.props.myField.onChange(true);
```

and this works under normal usage (non unit test scenario).

I have a very basic knowledge of sinon (specifically using spies) but I'm not sure if this is what I need or if I can just pass a normal function to onChange in my unit test.

I really appreciate any help on this!

EDIT:

It was pointed out in the comments that it wasn't completely clear what I am trying to achieve. What I am specifically trying to do is manipulate the value property of myField from inside the onChange method as I want to be able to test the effect that value change has on my component.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you can pass any function you want.

Comment: Hey @DaveNewton, Sorry if it wasn't entirely clear. What I am specifically trying to do is manipulate the value property of myField from inside the onChange method as I want to be able to test the effect that value change has on my component.

Comment: Why inside the `onChange` method? That seems to conflate two different aspects of component behavior. If you want to test functionality of `onChange` then just test that method. If you want to test functionality of specific values on the rest of the component then set a value and test whatever part of the component is related.

Comment: You make a very good point @DaveNewton, I could just explicitly pass a true for the value and test and test the other parts of the component to react accordingly. I can also spy on the onChange method and assert that it has been called. That should sufficiently test what needs to be tested.